# How do make a image button that also ripples?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

I tried to use Stack and InkWell but the code just gets longer and it seems to have issues. Also it doesn't ripple.

This is what I have:

[image]

It is what I want but I need to text to be at the center (adding padding or center doesn't work). The ripple also doesn't work.

Here is the code but I would rather start from scratch rather than fix my code. I don't think my way is the best way to go about at it.

```
class Dates extends StatelessWidget {
  const Dates({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Container(
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 1,
          childAspectRatio: 3,
          children: [
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                print("tapped");
              },
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 180,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('images/background/1.jpg'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover)
                      ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "First",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 30,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 70,
                          ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Hello")),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Hello")),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You want this type of image is top of card https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ28GZWLhcznnUA3WeJbXJ0I63AUUD2q_r-mQ&usqp=CAU

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for.

```
 Ink.image(
              image: AssetImage(
                "assets/ocen.jpg",
              ),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "First",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. But from what you have mentioned, I think you should read more about how the stack works. If you want to add the ripple effect to that image by just using inkwell, then the inkwell should be the last child of the stack(last in the children's list) The image will be at the bottom and inkwell at the top, and for the ripple effect use material the parent of the inkwell.